# Create a new variable based on several conditions in R

Tags: r

I would like to create a new variable based on several conditions on the columns `5 to 10`.
This new variable should get a `1` depending on a list of conditions. Then, if there is either `C71.2`, or `C75.1`, or `G45.1`, we should a `1` in the new column, otherwise a `0`.

Here are the data.

```
structure(list(Participant.ID = c(1000171L, 1000368L, 1000370L, 
1000414L, 1000672L, 1000726L, 1000921L, 1001044L, 1001141L, 1001366L
), MET.minutes.per.week.for.vigorous.activity...Instance.0 = c(0L, 
NA, 720L, 0L, 800L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, NA), MET.minutes.per.week.for.moderate.activity...Instance.0 = c(0L, 
NA, 720L, 0L, 420L, NA, NA, 0L, 40L, NA), Summed.MET.minutes.per.week.for.all.activity...Instance.0 = c(132, 
NA, 2595, 99, 1880, NA, NA, 0, 106, NA), Operative.procedures...OPCS4 = c("[\"C71.2 Phacoemulsification of lens\"", 
"[\"E36.9 Unspecified diagnostic endoscopic examination of larynx\"", 
"[\"A52.1 Therapeutic lumbar epidural injection\"", "[\"O29.1 Subacromial decompression\"", 
"[\"W31.9 Unspecified other autograft of bone\"", "[\"G45.1 Fibreoptic endoscopic examination of upper gastrointestinal tract and biopsy of lesion of upper gastrointestinal tract\"", 
"[\"C71.2 Phacoemulsification of lens\"", "[\"E49.9 Unspecified diagnostic fibreoptic endoscopic examination of lower respiratory tract\"", 
"[\"A38.1 Extirpation of lesion of meninges of cortex of brain\"", 
"[\"G15.7 Fibreoptic endoscopic insertion of expanding covered metal stent into oesophagus\""
), X = c("C75.1 Insertion of prosthetic replacement for lens NEC", 
"E49.2 Diagnostic fibreoptic endoscopic examination of lower respiratory tract and lavage of lesion of lower respiratory tract", 
"A57.7 Injection of therapeutic substance around spinal nerve root", 
"S06.5 Excision of lesion of skin of head or neck NEC", "W37.1 Primary total prosthetic replacement of hip joint using cement", 
"H15.4 Closure of colostomy", "C75.1 Insertion of prosthetic replacement for lens NEC", 
"G45.1 Fibreoptic endoscopic examination of upper gastrointestinal tract and biopsy of lesion of upper gastrointestinal tract", 
"U05.1 Computed tomography of head", "G16.2 Diagnostic fibreoptic endoscopic ultrasound examination of oesophagus"
), X.1 = c("C86.5 Fluorescein angiography of eye", "F36.2 Biopsy of lesion of tonsil", 
"A60.4 Radiofrequency controlled thermal destruction of peripheral nerve", 
"S27.5 Local flap of skin to head or neck NEC", "X50.1 Direct current cardioversion", 
"H15.9 Unspecified other exteriorisation of colon", "C79.2 Vitrectomy using pars plana approach", 
"H22.1 Diagnostic fibreoptic endoscopic examination of colon and biopsy of lesion of colon", 
"U05.2 Magnetic resonance imaging of head", "G45.1 Fibreoptic endoscopic examination of upper gastrointestinal tract and biopsy of lesion of upper gastrointestinal tract"
), X.2 = c("C90.1 Topical anaesthetic", "K62.2 Percutaneous transluminal ablation of atrial wall for atrial flutter", 
"A73.5 Injection of therapeutic substance around peripheral nerve", 
"T62.2 Excision of bursa NEC", "X99.8 No procedure performed", 
"H22.9 Unspecified diagnostic endoscopic examination of colon", 
"C79.5 Internal tamponade of retina using gas", "N11.3 Eversion of hydrocele sac", 
"X99.8 No procedure performed", "J18.3 Total cholecystectomy NEC"
), X.3 = c("G45.1 Fibreoptic endoscopic examination of upper gastrointestinal tract and biopsy of lesion of upper gastrointestinal tract", 
"U05.1 Computed tomography of head", "E59.1 Needle biopsy of lesion of lung", 
"T65.2 Excision of lesion of tendon", "Y66.8 Other specified harvest of bone", 
"H33.5 Rectosigmoidectomy and closure of rectal stump and exteriorisation of bowel", 
"C80.1 Peel of epiretinal fibroglial membrane", "U13.6 Computed tomography of bone", 
"Y46.2 Frontal open approach to contents of cranium", "J37.3 Direct puncture operative cholangiography"
), X.4 = c("G45.9 Unspecified diagnostic fibreoptic endoscopic examination of upper gastrointestinal tract", 
"U20.1 Transthoracic echocardiography", "G45.1 Fibreoptic endoscopic examination of upper gastrointestinal tract and biopsy of lesion of upper gastrointestinal tract", 
"W84.4 Endoscopic decompression of joint", "Z75.6 Acetabulum", 
"S35.2 Meshed split autograft of skin NEC", "C80.2 Peel of internal limiting membrane", 
"U33.1 Polysomnography", "Y53.8 Other specified approach to organ under image control", 
"J43.9 Unspecified diagnostic endoscopic retrograde examination of bile duct and pancreatic duct"
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you very much!
Very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These column names are nightmarish! But, building on this answer
[R Paste string into a new column if there is a match across multiple columns by a specified string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73669105/r-paste-string-into-a-new-column-if-there-is-a-match-across-multiple-columns-by)
I think this is what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(match = str_subset(c_across(5:10), "C71.2|C75.1|G45.1")[1]) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(match=ifelse(is.na(match),0,1))
```

Comment: Yes they are ! Thank you, it does work very well!